# Why am I getting this error? No Scala(Long)Signature annotation in classfile with ScalaSignature attribute: class JUnit4

Tags: scala

I am trying to follow the example code in the below link in Intellij. When I try to run the code, I am getting the below error. Can you please help me understand why?

https://stdatalabs.com/2016/09/spark-streaming-part-3-real-time/

```
Error:scalac: Error: assertion failed: 
  No Scala(Long)Signature annotation in classfile with ScalaSignature attribute: class JUnit4
     while compiling: E:\Practice\ScalaPractice2\src\test\scala\ScalaPractice2\MySpec.scala
        during phase: globalPhase=typer, enteringPhase=namer
     library version: version 2.13.0
    compiler version: version 2.13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely because one of your dependencies has a version incompatible with Scala 2.13 (especially since 2.13 was only released this June and the tutorial was written in 2016). If you followed previous links and are using Maven you can use `mvn dependency:tree` and look for anything containing `_2.12` or `_2.11`. But for Scala, [SBT](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) build system is preferred and it's what you'll find if you look in Spark tutorials.